# Round up all currencies on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop with two available currencies: USD and ILS.

I want all prices to be rounded up, without any decimals, for all currencies. I want them to be trimmed at least on the shop & cart page.

I tried using the following PHP code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );
function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
  $total = round( $total, 1 );
  return $total;
}

/**
 * Trim zeros in price decimals
 **/
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```

And I also tried using this code as well:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', 'change_prices_decimals', 20, 1 );
function change_prices_decimals( $decimals ){
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() )
        $decimals = 0;
    return $decimals;
}
```

I can't seem to get rid of the decimals in the secondary currency.
Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: `number_format((float)$number, 0, '', '');` Have you tried this?

Comment: Hey, where would you add it? I am still learning PHP so if you can be more specific it will help a lot :) @Fresz

Comment: It needs to convert every price, so at the product, cart and checkout. Anywhere you are returning price - you will need to do the rounding up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to round the product price. these filters will round it when WC tries to get the price of a product. **Make sure to place it in your functions.php file in your active theme folder**:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'get_product_rounded_price', 200, 2 );

function get_product_rounded_price($value, $product) {
return number_format(ceil($value),0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, it didn't trim decimals and it didn't round up cents for my different currency. :(

Comment: @RoziBuber Please see my edited answer. Two reasons why it may not succeed: or it was a variable product, or you may not placed it in the right place. The updated code covers variable products as well.